# google maps business api v3 override unauthorized alert

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We recently upgraded our app to use the business version of the google maps API v3.  According to:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/guide#URLs

we have to authorize all end-users of our application (those running the server-side code that we deploy) to use our maps implementation.

If a user tries to deploy our code on a server whose fqdn hasn't been included (by us) in the authorized URL list on google's portal, they see the following alert on page load:

```
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application.  
This site is not authorized to use the Google Maps client ID 
provided.  If you are the owner of this applicattion, you can 
learn more about registereing URLs here: https://
developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/
guide#URLs
```

and the map functionality obviously doesn't work.  This is all fine and good, but the message is a little unfriendly.  Is it possible to replace this alert with something that we can define?  E.g.  "you appear to be running an unauthorized version, please contact us at xxx@yyy.com".

Otherwise, is there some test we can perform prior to fetching the maps javascript library that will let us display an alert dialog there?

Thanks!